# MySQLi Wrapper - Weird where clause issue?

Tags: php, mysqli, wrapper

I am currently using joshcam's [PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#where-query) which has quite a few stars and forks. However, even with all of the attention it gets, it seems like it's missing some features — or I am misunderstanding how to use it.

When I use the where clause function he created, the variables I input don't seem to have quotations around them. It's like I have to manually add the quotation marks to the beginning and end of the variables, even though they are prepared statements and that's counter intuitive.

I tried reaching him but no luck, so here I am.

Here's example code:

```
$db->where ('name', 'John Doe');
$results = $db->get ('users');
echo $db->getLastQuery();
```

Yet, here is what it outputs:

> SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = John Doe

So unless I am missing something (and I carefully scanned the documentation), I am going to have to put quotes around every single variable in the where function? Why did he not incorporate this and why do so many people like this wrapper if such an obvious feature is missing? The whole benefit of prepared statements is that they handle the quotations and everything, so this is counter intuitive if I am doing it correctly.

EDIT: To take it one step further. On his documentation under the "Where" clause bit, it says:

> OR CASE

```
$db->where ('firstName', 'John'); $db->orWhere ('firstName', 'Peter');
$results = $db->get ('users');
// Gives: SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstName='John' OR firstName='peter'
```

Yet when I place that exact code into my file and echo out the query, it shows no quotation marks still.

Comment: The whole point of having prepared statements is to avoid quoting and inserting values into the query body. Based on a quick look at the code you linked to, it seems that it generates and executes the query safely, and the `replacePlaceholders` method (used only to build a copy of the query with inlined placeholder values and save it into `_lastQuery` for future reference, not execute it) is the problem.

Comment: Does `$results` actually return valid results? If so, the reported query is not the one it actually ran. There's a good number of issues opened on the project page, and none mention needing to quote as far as I can tell, so I wonder if it isn't actually an issue?

Comment: @halfer: the problem is in [this line](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L812), where the placeholder is replaced with its value *without quotes*. But that method is only used to populate the `lastQuery` property, not to actually execute the query.